# How to join each order with its price?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, database-management

I have two tables named PRICES and ORDERS.

PRICES

| Product_ID | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 100 |

ORDERS

| CUSTOMER_ID | Product_ID | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 456 | 2 | 5 |
| 789 | 2 | 2 |
| 327 | 1 | 7 |

I want to join these two tables to get below expected output:

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| Product_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | QUANTITY | PRICE | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 3 | 50 | 150 |
| 2 | 456 | 5 | 100 | 500 |
| 2 | 789 | 2 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 327 | 7 | 50 | 350 |

Comment: What part of `JOIN` do you not understand?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a code writing service. We help with programming problems. Try it until you run into a problem

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inner join to get price for each product in orders table:

```
Select o.customer_id, p.product_id, o.quantity, p.price
from PRICES p inner join ORDERS o on p.product_id=o.product_id
```